# Cannot convert dynamicJsonObject to Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, json

I'm using a dynamicJsonDeserializer to deserialize my json and it works just fine.

```
public class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public DynamicJsonObject(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        this.Dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this.Dictionary[binder.Name];

        if (result is IDictionary<string, object>)
        {
            result = new DynamicJsonObject(result as IDictionary<string, object>);
        }
        else if (result is ArrayList && (result as ArrayList) is IDictionary<string, object>)
        {
            result = new List<DynamicJsonObject>((result as ArrayList).ToArray().Select(x => new DynamicJsonObject(x as IDictionary<string, object>)));
        }
        else if (result is ArrayList)
        {
            result = new List<object>((result as ArrayList).ToArray());
        }

        return this.Dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name);
    }
}
public class DynamicJsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

        if (type == typeof(object))
        {
            return new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new Type[] { typeof(object) })); }
    }
}
```

Why can I not convert a DynamicJsonObject to a Dictionary so I can do stuff with it ?

```
dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(jsonResponse, typeof(object));
Dictionary<string, object> test = new Dictionary<string, object>(dynamicObject.Dictionary); //cannot do this
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was easily solved by making the Dictionary public.

Comment: Reviewers: this is an answer. It explains how they solved the problem.